# Live DVD boot - lost Launcher in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, multiple-monitors, livedvd

I wanted to check out the latest (12.04) version of Ubuntu to see if the Unity shell had improved, so I booted my Dell Latitude with a live DVD.

My laptop is connected to a docking station, and I have two monitors hooked into it.  Happily, the system started properly and even detected the two monitors.  Oddly, Unity's launcher bar appeared on each screen.

When I pressed the Ubuntu Dash button, I saw a close button ("x") to kill the Launcher on the right monitor, but then I saw that I could close the left monitor's Launcher too. When I did that, I saw no way to respawn the Launcher.

My question is two-fold: a) how do I relaunch Launcher if it's been closed, and b) how do I configure the system to only load a Launcher on the left monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Press the ALT key to start the Launcher. There is a closely related question here [Launcher shows up on the wrong monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127859/launcher-shows-up-on-the-wrong-monitor)
It would help to know what computer/model/video card also

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, yes that link may help. But it is preferable to include the answer right here.

Comment: This did not work. Pressing the Alt key looked like it loaded an empty frame with only a red X visible in the top left corner.  The launcher never reappeared and neither did Dash.